Example of an Infinite-Dimensional Non-Commutative Division Ring over a Finite Field
According to Wedderburn's little theorem, any finite-dimensional division ring over a finite field must be a commutative division ring, i.e., it is a field.
So the question arises: What about infinite-dimensional division rings over a finite field? That is, is there an infinite-dimensional division ring that is not commutative over a finite field?

Surely we can construct cyclic division algebras over fields like $\Bbb{F}_q(t)$, $t$ transcendental. I suspect that there is an older question with examples...

So far this is the closest hit, but perhaps not very useful here.

How about this?

Instead of "not a field over a finite field" you mean not finite dimensional over a field right?

@rschwieb Yes, because if a division ring is a finite-dimensional vector space over a finite field, then the division ring must be a field.

I agree that's technically correct although not the obvious way to say it, in my view.

My example in Izaak's link should do the trick.

Yes, I have seen your counterexample. Thank you.

Let me think about how to rephrase it.
